# How to access results from async.parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, promise, async.js

I'm trying to execute two Mongoose queries using `async.parallel` and then do something with the results. However, when I try to access these results as `results[0]` and `results[1]` they are returned as Promises:

```
Promise {
_c: [],
_a: undefined,
_s: 0,
_d: false,
_v: undefined,
_h: 0,
_n: false } ]
```

I'm still familiarizing myself with async and promises and am not sure how to actually access the documents that should be returned by the two queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My current function:

```
export const getItems = (req, res) => {
    const itemId = "57f59c5674746a6754df0d4b";
    const personId = "584483b631566f609ebcc833";

    const asyncTasks = [];

    asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
        try {
            const result = Item.findOne({ _id: itemId }).exec();
            callback(null, result);
        } catch (error) {
            callback(error);
        }
    });

    asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
        try {
            const result = User.findOne({ _id: personId }).exec();
            callback(null, result);
        } catch (error) {
            callback(error);
        }
    });

    async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        const result1 = results[0];
        const result2 = results[1];
        console.log('result' + result1);

    });
}
```

Comment: You should use *either* async.js *or* promises, but not both.

Comment: @Bergi - I was going to add that, but can't actually find any (reasonable) discussion regarding why using both is a bad idea - I agree it's a bad idea, I just can't justify why :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I think I discussed in a few answers of mine, but can't find a good link either. The point is basically that when you mix nodebacks with promises, doing correct error handling is even more mistake-prone, and you basically forfeit all the advantages that promises have over callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the documentation, `exec()` returns a promise, if you want to use a callback you pass that as a parameter to exec - like so

```
asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
    Item.findOne({ _id: itemId }).exec(callback);
});

asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
    User.findOne({ _id: personId }).exec(callback);
});
```

Alternatively, using only Promises

```
export const getItems = (req, res) => {
    const itemId = "57f59c5674746a6754df0d4b";
    const personId = "584483b631566f609ebcc833";

    const promises = [];

    promises.push(Item.findOne({ _id: itemId }).exec());
    promises.push(User.findOne({ _id: personId }).exec());

    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(results) {
        const result1 = results[0];
        const result2 = results[1];
        console.log('result' + result1);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know which answer you went with as I'm not even sure the first answer is 100% correct!